# alloy listView android - dynamic data disappears when scrolling

Tags: android, listview, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium, appcelerator-alloy

Created a basic `listView` to test it out. ios version works as intended. On a genymotion android emulator, when scrolling, the bound dynamic data gets overwritten with blanks/null. This can be demonstrated easily using this [gist listed here](https://gist.github.com/mjstelly/b7cbfdfc3efda5a90636) on a generic alloy test app. Just add code to the respective `index.*` files. You'll need a recent version of `moment.js` in the `/lib` directory.

Why is it overwritten? I suspect it has something to do with how `listView` reuses components. How do I fix it?

Thanks.

Comment: I could indeed reproduce this with your code.

It looks like you've found a (weird) bug. Please check if this is a known issue at the [Appcelerator JIRA](https://jira.appcelerator.org/). If it's not, create a ticket, link to this question but also provide reproducible code, steps and environment information in the ticket itself. Don't forget to drop a link to the ticket here so that others can watch it with you.

Comment: is this issue fixed? Can you please post the ticket link here if there is any?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In working through the problem, I found that the issue is the horizontal layout that you have applied to the `.row` class in your index.tss file. If you remove that layout, then your list view will behave as expected.

**Why is this happening?**
Well to be honest i'm not sure, but I have a guess. In the effort to minimize memory, listViews only render items that are visible on the screen. In this case when the item goes off screen, then when it becomes visible again, its possible that the layout isn't rendering properly due to conflicts with the other styles that are applied (and conflict) with your intended layout.

Comment: This was soooo dang obscure. Bert, you're my hero! You both deserve beers at our next soiree!